# IE8 looking for images from css in wrong location

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I've got the following entry in my style sheet:

```
html, body 
{ 
  background: #eee url('../Content/Images/texture.jpg') center;
}
```

The location of my style sheet is

```
C:\Websites\MyWebsite\Themes\Contoso\Styles\Site.css
```

The location of the texture image is

```
C:\Websites\MyWebsite\Themes\Contoso\Content\Images\texture.jpg
```

IE8 seems to have some issues resolving the relative path.
Browsing the url www.mysite.com/Clients/12345/Dashboard causes the following entries in my log file:

```
2013-02-18 00:54:40 131.203.91.104 GET /Clients/12345/Content/Images/texture.jpg
 - 443 9260085 222.155.91.136 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+Trident/4.0;+BTRS124349;+GTB7.4;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.4506.2152;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729) 
404 0 64 187

...

2013-02-18 00:54:40 131.203.91.104 GET /Themes/Contoso/Content/Images/texture.jpg
 - 443 9260085 222.155.91.136 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+Trident/4.0;+BTRS124349;+GTB7.4;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.4506.2152;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729)
304 0 0 436
```

And that first URL it requests changes based on the URL it is requested from.
This happens to 3 or 4 other images on my site, but all other images are fine.
I'd like to sort it out as these 404's are clogging up my error logs

Anyone seen this behaviour before?

Cheers

Comment: are you logging referers? check which pages the bad requests are coming from.

Comment: Not logging referrers. However looking at the flow of the logs, it looks like it's just users browsing through the site, and everytime they request a new page that 404 error happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the 404's went away after changing the css to:

```
html, body 
{ 
  background: #eee url('/Themes/Contoso/Content/Images/texture.jpg') center;
}
```